# How do i pass variables to another page in php?

Tags: php, html

I have moved over the validation to the bikeInfo.php file. Not much changes have been made to the code, but not sure why the validation is not being processed... appreciate the help!

```
<?php 
    
    $nameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $sErr = $errorMsg = "";
    $name = $phone = $email = $serial = $type = $formSubmit = $description = "";  
?>
<head>
    <title>Register your bikes!</title> 
</head>
<style>
    body {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center; 
        padding: 8px;
    }
    div.sellerInfo {
        position: relative; 
        top: 50px;
 
    }
    
    .error {
        position: absolute;
        color: red;
    }
    
    
</style>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="bikeInfo.php">
    <b style="font-size: 20px;">Bike Information</b>
    </br></br>
        <div class="sellerInfo">
        Name: 
        <input type="text" name="sName" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        
        Phone: 
        <input type="text" name="sNum" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"/>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        
        Email: 
        <input type="text" name="sEmail" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        
        Serial: 
        <input type="text" placeholder="yy-nnn-cc" name="serial" value="<?php echo $serial;?>"/>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $sErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        
        Type: 
        <input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $type;?>"/>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $errorMsg;?></span>
        <br><br>
                
        Description: 
        <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="50" value="<?php echo $description;?>"></textarea>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit"/>
        </div><br><br><br>
        
        </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**This is my bikeInfo.php file which does validation and displaying of the submitted values. Not sure am i suppose to separate them...**

```
<?php
    //set to empty strings 
    $name = $phone = $email = $serial = $type = $formSubmit = $description = ""; 
    $nameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $sErr = $errorMsg = ""; 
        
    if (isset($_POST["formSubmit"]))
    {   

        if (empty($_POST["sName"])) 
        {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
            
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST['sName']); 
        }
        
        //validate phone number 
        if (empty($_POST["sNum"]))
        {
            $phoneErr = "Phone number is required"; 
        } else {    
            $phone = test_input($_POST['sNum']);
                if (!is_numeric($phone)) //check for letters 
                {
                     $phoneErr = "No letters allowed";
                }
        } 
        
        //validate email 
        if (empty($_POST["sEmail"]))
        {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";  
        } else { 
            $email = test_input($_POST['sEmail']); 
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                {  
                    $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
                }
        }
        
        //validate serial 
        if (empty($_POST["serial"]))
        {
            $sErr = "Serial number is required"; 
        } else {
            $serial = test_input($_POST['serial']);
                //determing the pattern of the serial no. yy-nnnn-cc
            if (!preg_match("/[0-9][0-9]\-\d{3}\-[a-z]{2}/", $serial))
                {
                    $sErr = "Format is yy-nnn-cc"; 
                }
        }
        
        //validate type 
        if (empty($_POST["type"]))
        {
            $errorMsg = "Type is required";  
        } else {
            $type = test_input($_POST["type"]); 
        }
    }
    
    
    
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
        }
    
    


?>
<html>
<style> 
    .body {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center; padding: 20px">Bike listings</h1>
    <?php
    $listings = $name . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . $email . "<br>" . $serial . "<br>" . $type . "<br>" . $description;
    echo "<div style='text-align:center; padding: 50px'>$listings</div>"; 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code or extracts from it? The HTML is not correctly formed

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius actual codes. In what way is not correctly formed?

Comment: @KenLee I did that but my form still doesnt get validated

Comment: The PHP on the first page does nothing if the form is submitted to another location - only the code on `bikeinfo.php` will be used

Comment: If you submit the form directly to bikeinfo then obviously it won't pass through your validation code because your original script doesn't run again. There are several ways you could potentially design this kind of thing. It would make some sense, for example, to must put the validation code in the bikeinfo file, or in a file which is then required by bikeinfo, or just not to have a separate bikeinfo page to begin with and put everything in one script

Comment: No `<html>` opening tag at the start of the HTML document, a style tag between the `head` and `body`, the `<html>` tag just before the `body`. Similar mistakes in bikeinfo page. the `</br>` tag should be `<br />` or simply `<br>`

Comment: (1) For client-side validation, you may use javascript. (2) For server-side validation, you should put the validation statements in the  bikeInfo.php

Comment: What is `$formSubmit`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius $formSubmit was in another function but i took it off. I've moved the validation to the bikeInfo.php file, but my form doesnt get validated still.. noted on the tags, have a bad habit on it

Comment: Update the question to show us the latest version of the code please, we can't tell what might still be wrong without that, and having only the vaguest description of the problem.

Comment: @ADyson yep have done it, thank you

Comment: Ok so the problem currently is that you might validate the data and set all the error variables such as $nameErr, $emailErr etc, but you don't actually use them for anything. I kind of assumed you were also going to move across the HTML where you were echoing those values.

Comment: @ADyson yes, would need to access the variables across the files

Comment: @HelpAGirlOut no, you'd need to move the code which echoes the error variables into the bikeinfo page along with the validation code. But anyway the answer below is a far more coherent, polished solution overall than yours anyway, I suggest simply using that rather than messing about any further.

Answer (score 3):

I had a little play about refactoring the code so that you could use a single page to perform both the validation and display. Perhaps it may be of use.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    $errors=array();
    $nameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $sErr = $errorMsg = '';
    $sName = $sNum = $sEmail = $serial = $type = $description = '';
    
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['sName'],
        $_POST['sNum'],
        $_POST['sEmail'],
        $_POST['serial'],
        $_POST['type']
    )){
        # modified to accept uppercase chars at end and limited to 2 integers at atart
        $pttn='/[0-9]{2}\-\d{3}\-[a-zA-Z]{2}/';
        
        # config to filter POST vars
        $args=array(
            'sName'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'sNum'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'sEmail'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
            'serial'        =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'type'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'description'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        
        # test for unaccounted POST fields - possibly malicious
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
            if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $args ) ) ){
                $errors[]=sprintf('Unknown field %s',$field);
            }
        }
        
        
        if( empty( $errors ) ){
        
            # rebuild the POST array with only filtered values
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            
            # extract known values from POST array into variables
            extract( $_POST );
            
            
            #error messages
            $nameErr=empty( $sName ) ? 'Name is required' : '';
            $phoneErr=empty( $sNum ) ? 'Phone number is required' : '';
            $emailErr=empty( $sEmail ) ? 'Email is required' : '';
            $sErr=empty( $serial ) ? 'Serial number is required' : '';
            $errorMsg=empty( $type ) ? 'Type is required' : '';
            
            
            # Validate particular variables
            $sEmail=filter_var( $sEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
            # to filter the phone number might remove leading zero and thus appear invalid
            
            # possibly reassign error message variables
            if( !preg_match( $pttn, $serial ) )$sErr='Invalid Serial. The format is: yy-nnn-cc';
            if( !$sEmail )$emailErr='Invalid email format';
            if( !$sNum )$phoneErr='Invalid phone number. No letters allowed!';
            
            
            
            # save to database, email somewhere, write text etc etc
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register your bikes!</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin:auto;
                text-align:center; 
                padding:8px;
            }
            div.sellerInfo {
                top:50px;
            }
            .error {
                position:absolute;
                color:red;
            }
            section{
                margin:2rem auto;
                width:300px;
                padding:1rem;
                display:block;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
            section *{
                text-align:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <b>Bike Information</b>
            <div class='sellerInfo'>
                <div>
                    Name: 
                    <input type='text' name='sName' value='<?php echo $sName;?>' />
                    <span class='error'>* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Phone: 
                    <input type='text' name='sNum' value='<?php echo $sNum;?>' />
                    <span class='error'>* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Email: 
                    <input type='text' name='sEmail' value='<?php echo $sEmail;?>' />
                    <span class='error'>* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Serial: 
                    <input type='text' placeholder='yy-nnn-cc' name='serial' value='<?php echo $serial;?>' />
                    <span class='error'>* <?php echo $sErr;?></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Type: 
                    <input type='text' name='type' value='<?php echo $type;?>' />
                    <span class='error'>* <?php echo $errorMsg;?></span>
                </div>
                <div>   
                    Description: 
                    <textarea name='description' rows='5' cols='50' value='<?php echo $description;?>'></textarea>
                </div>
                
                
                <input type='submit' />
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
                $sName,
                $sNum,
                $sEmail,
                $serial,
                $type,
                $description
            )){
                if( empty( $errors ) ){
                    
                    printf('
                        <section>
                            <h1 style="text-align:center; padding: 20px">Bike listings</h1>
                            <ul>
                                <li>%s</li>
                                <li>%s</li>
                                <li>%s</li>
                                <li>%s</li>
                                <li>%s</li>
                                <li>%s</li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>',
                        $sName,
                        $sNum,
                        $sEmail,
                        $serial,
                        $type,
                        $description
                    );
                }else{
                    foreach( $errors as $error )printf('<div class="error">%s</div>',$error);
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```